# Create Workfront Note object using API with specific entryDate

Tags: attask, workfront-api

I am sending the following POST request to the Workfront API in order to create a new Note object and set the submission date to January 7th, 2020 at 11:58:30AM:

```
https://<myorg>.my.workfront.com/attask/api/v15.0/note?
   updates={"noteText":"testing!", "entryDate":"2020-01-07T11:58:30","objCode":"NOTE",
   "topNoteObjCode":"PROJ", "projectID":"<validProjectID>", "customerID":"<validCustomerID>",
   "ownerID":"<validUserID>", "topObjID":"<validProjectID>", "formatEntryDate":"YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss"}
   &apiKey=<myKey>&method=post&sessionID=<mySessionID>
```

But the note is being posted at the time of submission instead of my specified entryDate:

```
"data": {
    "ID": "645cfddd001ccdfd9723c0c95fbc2d39",
    "objCode": "NOTE",
    "auditType": "NO",
    "entryDate": "2023-05-11T10:38:21:504-0400",
    "noteText": "testing!",
    "subject": null
}
```

How can I force the entryDate to be my desired date? The API Explorer (https://developer.adobe.com/workfront/api-explorer/) is not much help unfortunately.

Also, how could I set the auditType?